# Is there an .lxf file resource of production Lego sets?

Tags: sets, ldd

Is there an .lxf file resource site of production Lego sets? Specifically, I am looking for the Millennium Falcon 10179 lxf file, to load into Lego Digital Designer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Eurobricks](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?act=idx) forum has a [topic](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=41226) dedicated to user created LDD files of existing LEGO sets.

There are currently four different versions of the #10179 Millennium Falcon made by different users:

- [yellost](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=41226&st=600#entry797007) (23 August 2010) [image: Image Preview]
- [bbqqq](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=41226&st=1025#entry853467) (12 November 2010)
- [Calabar](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=41226&st=2650#entry1413264) (20 October 2012) [image: Image Preview]
- [kcoon](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=41226&st=3475#entry1765696) (16 December 2013) [image: Image Preview]

There is also a [topic](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=48285) for official LEGO sets re-created in [ldraw](/questions/tagged/ldraw).

Comment: There's also an article on the LDraw site on [how files represeting official models should be created](http://www.ldraw.org/article/593.html) which hints at a repository, but doesn't link to it...